# To Dispose or Not to Dispose - IDisposable Passed as Function Parameter

Tags: object-model, dispose

If an `IDisposable` SharePoint object is passed into a function, does an explicit `Dispose()` call need to be made on it?

Example:

```
public void TheCallingFunction()
{
    SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("WebName"))
    {
        DoSomethingRad(web);
    }
}

public void DoSomethingRad(SPWeb web)
{
    // Do something that's borderline awesome

    web.Dispose(); // Yes or no?
}
```

Roger Lamb's [SharePoint 2007 and WSS 3.0 Dispose Patterns by Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rogerla/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example) doesn't cover this directly (really more of a C# question than an SP question I suppose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an `IDisposable` SharePoint object is passed into a function, does an explicit `Dispose()` call need to made on it?

No. Generally, whoever created the object is also responsible for disposing of it. In your example, `TheCallingFunction` might have had some other use for the web after `DoSomethingRad` returns. See also [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085939/who-should-call-dispose-on-idisposable-objects-when-passed-into-another-object)

Most of the time calling Dispose() twice in a row won't break your program, but it might lead to unexpected results when you're trying to use an object that's been disposed.

Comment: That was exactly what I thought, I just wanted to verify if passing the object created another instance or not. Just like C++, if you create it, you delete it. Trying to clean up someone else's code...

Comment: You might want to `DoSomethingRad(SPContext.Current.Web);` or `DoSomethingRad(web); SPList awesome = web.GetList("RadList");`, in which case it would be a bad thing to dispose of the object in `DoSomethingRad()`

Answer (score 4):

No. If you do, you might actually get an error, because the using statement under "TheCallingFunction" would call dispose on "web" after "DoSomethingRad" already called "Dispose()".

- As a rule of thumb, you have to look at your public method as a black box that just does what you expect it to do. To follow the Single-Responsibility Principle just do "DoSomethingRad" on your case, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, using will dispose the object... So you don't need to explicitly dispose the object when passing as parameter to some other function!

As you can also see if you try to pass the object as ref to the function, it will give compile-time error that a variable in using can't be passed as reference!